# Best approach to read and write large files with collective MPI-IO

Tags: io, fortran, mpi

I would like to read and write large data sets in Fortran using MPI-IO. My preferred approach would be to use a MPI type defined with MPI_type_create_subarray with a single dimension to describe the view of each process to the file. My Fortran code thus looks like this:

```
  ! A contiguous type to describe the vector per element.
  ! MPI_TYPE_CONTIGUOUS(COUNT, OLDTYPE, NEWTYPE, IERROR)
  call MPI_Type_contiguous(nComponents, rk_mpi, &
    &                      me%vectype, iError)
  call MPI_Type_commit( me%vectype, iError )

  ! A subarray to describe the view of this process on the file.
  ! MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(ndims, array_of_sizes, array_of_subsizes,
  !                          array_of_starts, order, oldtype, newtype, ierror)
  call MPI_Type_create_subarray( 1, [ globElems ], [ locElems ], &
    &                           [ elemOff ], MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, &
    &                           me%vectype, me%ftype, iError)
```

However, array_of_sizes and array_of_starts, describing global quantities are just "normal" integers in the MPI-Interface. Thus there is a limit at about 2 billion elements with this approach.
Is there another interface, which uses MPI_OFFSET_KIND for these global values?
The only way to work around this, I see so far, is using the displacement option in the MPI_File_set_view instead of defining the view with the help of the subarray MPI type. However this "feels" wrong. Would you expect a performance impact in either approach for collective IO? Does anybody know, if this interface will change in MPI-3?
Maybe I should use some other MPI type?

What is the recommended solution here to write large data files with collective IO efficiently in parallel to disk?

Comment: can't you compile mpi to use 8-byte integers? (intel `-i8`, gcc `-fdefault-integer-8`)

Comment: I'd rather stay with the installations provided by the HPC hosts.

Answer (score 3):

Help is coming.

In MPI-3, there will be datatype manipulation routines that use [MPI_Count](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/new-things-in-mpi-3-mpi_count/) instead of an int.   For backwards compatability (groan) the existing routines won't change, but you should be able to make your type.

But for now..
For subarray in particular, though, this isn't usually thought of as a huge issue at the moment - even for a 2d array, indices of 2 billion give you an array size of 4x10<sup>18</sup> which is admittedly pretty large (but exactly the sort of numbers targetted for exascale-type computing).   In higher dimensions, it's even larger.

In 1d, though, a list of numbers 2 billion long is only ~8GB which isn't by any stretch big data, and I think that's the situation you find yourself in.   My suggstion would be to leave it in the form you have it now for as long as you can.   Is there a common factor in the local elements?   You can work around this by bundling up the types in units of (say) 10 vectypes if that works - for your code it shouldn't matter, but it would reduce by that same factor the numbers in the locElements and globElements.  Otherwise, yes, you could always use the displacement field in file set view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply. Unfortunately the MPI_Count stuff won't help as far as I understand it, as it does not change the subarray interface, or provide a new interface to define such a data type where the global extent can not be covered by a 4 byte integer. Unfortunately I also can not easily find a common discriminator larger than one across all my partitions, as a common distribution is for example n = globElem/p for all partitions, but for the first mod(globElem/p) partitions n+1.

Comment: Oof.  Yeah, I'm expecting MPI_Count to make its way into other routines eventually but not for 3.0.   You might be out of luck, then, and have to go with the manual displacement approach.   Alternately, depending on what you do with the data, you could have a smaller pattern that repeats - either explicitly or by pretending it's a (say) 2d array - and still get pretty good load-balancing; but that'll depend on what you do with the 1d subarrays once they're loaded.